# Custom Site Column with DisplayPattern in SP2010

Tags: site-column

This was all trivial in 2007. In 2010 I can't get the AllItems.aspx view to use my DisplayPattern.

This is the outline of my site column definition:

```
<Field
     Type="Computed"
     Name="Test"
     DisplayName="Test"
     Group="Test"
     ID="{9D7643FD-3D46-231E-8425D-5250C7524521}">
     <DisplayPattern>
        <![CDATA[hello world]]>
     </DisplayPattern>
</Field>
```

The "hello world" text is shown in the display form, but not in AllItems. Has something changed here?

Comment: I've managed to do XSLT rendering for custom site columns, but it'd still be nice to know exactly what the state of DisplayPattern is too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might already know, the views are rendered by XSL list view web part and hence the rendering mechanism for views is now different than the list forms (display form that you referred) and different than MOSS 2007. What you need to do to have your own display pattern in SharePoint 2010 is well described in SDK here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx